# Saltar 2 datos al leer un archivo en C++

Tags: c++, lista, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++, fstream

Tengo un codigo que lee un archivo de texto el cual contiene solo datos enteros, y los une en una lista doble, pero tengo que saltarme los 2 primeros datos, es decir, si tengo los siguientes datos en el archivo `|1234|`, solo deberia leer desde el 3, lo cual no he podido lograr.

| Datos Txt | Lista |
| --- | --- |
| 1 2 3 4 5 6 | 3 4 5 6 |
| 9 10 3 7 8 0 | 3 7 8 0 |

```
void leermostrar(){ //Leer mostrar lista 

ifstream archivo;
archivo.open("entrada.txt",ios::in);
if(archivo.fail()){
    cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
while(!archivo.eof()){
    p=(nodo *) malloc (sizeof(struct nodo));
    archivo>>p->n;
    if(cab==NULL){
        p->ant=p->sig=NULL;
        cab=ult=p;  
     }
    else{
        p->sig=cab;
        p->ant=NULL;
        cab->ant=p;
        cab=p;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para recorrer un archivo desde cierta posición en C++ , encontre la funcion `archivo.seekg(3);` , de esta forma comenzaria a leer el archivo desde el tercer valor, esta linea se pone antes del while, ;)